# How to optimize video streaming

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, streaming

I am using my server to stream video on my local computer with VLC.

As usual, I'm putting the link on the network box and I'm waiting for the movie to stream (10K ms buffer).

The problem is that I'm still lagging sometimes in comparison with other services which have limited speed. My server has 1Gbit network and I'm having 8Mbps download speed. It should be very smooth without any problem. However, it isn't.
Is there any way to lower the frames for better performance? I know that many web players are optimizing the quality but I don't know which one to use and if this is gonna help me.

Could you please tell me how can I fix this?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you give us more info about what you're streaming and which technology you're using? Is it a simple download via HTTP? Put differently, is your server a simple web server? How are your videos compressed? How exactly does it fail, I mean, does it buffer frequently?

Comment: Im taking them froma the webserver with their link. The videos have different bitrate and cimpression, abot the failing its just like youtube. the video will stop and you will have to wait for the buffer to end